# How does howhunter.com get so much traffic from United States.

Tags: seo, traffic

I checked traffic of howhunter.com by similarweb.com. It shows 454.6k visits in the month of January. This website has very limited number of backlinks, very little social marketing. I wonder how this website is getting so much traffic.

Is it only because of large number of articles it has.

Comment: Also, questions must be related to your own website.